# Does $\mathbb{F}_2$ have a finite free resolution as an $\mathbb{F}_2[\mathbb{Q}]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

If $k$ is a field with 2 elements and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the additive group of rational numbers, is there a finite resolution of $k$ as $R=k[\mathbb{Q}]$ module?

By "finite" I mean a chain complex $$X=  R^{n_1}\rightarrow R^{n_{2}}\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow R^{n_{j}}\rightarrow k $$

where $R^{n}$ is a free generated R-module of dimension $n$.

> Edit: It will be fine if one can find a finite resolution of finitely generated projective $R$-module.

Comment: What action of $\mathbb{Q}$ are you considering on $k$? The trivial one?

Comment: @CaptainLama I use the standard augmentation homorphism $t: R\rightarrow k$ (homomorphism of rings), in particular the action of $Q$ on $k$ is trivial.

Comment: I assume you mean your chain complex to be exact and to start and end with $0$?  Otherwise such a chain complex exists trivially but doesn't have anything to do with what people would normally call a "resolution".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Indeed, $k$ is not even finitely presented, so there does not exist any exact sequence $$R^m\to R^n\to k\to 0$$ where $m$ and $n$ are finite.  (Note that the existence of such a sequence with finitely generated free modules is equivalent to the existence of one with finitely generated projective modules, since a finitely generated projective module is a summand of a finitely generated free module.)

More generally, let us show that if $k$ is any nonzero commutative ring and $G$ is any group that is not finitely generated, then $k$ is not finitely presented as a $k[G]$-module.  It suffices to show that the kernel $I$ of the augmentation $k[G]\to k$ is not finitely generated.  Since $I$ is generated by the elements $g-1$ for $g\in G$, if it were finitely generated then it would be generated by finitely many such elements $g_1-1,\dots,g_n-1$.  Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g_1,\dots,g_n$.  Let $M$ be the free $k$-module on the coset space $G/H$.  The left action of $G$ on $G/H$ gives a $k[G]$-module structure on $M$, with the quotient map $G\to G/H$ of $k$-sets inducing a surjective $k[G]$-module homomorphism $f:k[G]\to M$.  Moreover, $h-1$ is in the kernel of $f$ for all $h\in H$, so the kernel of $f$ contains $I$ so $f$ induces a surjective homomorphism $k\cong k[G]/I\to M$.  Since $k$ is free of rank $1$, this means $M$ is free of rank at most $1$.  But $M$ is free on $G/H$, so we must have $H=G$.  Since $H$ was generated by $g_1,\dots,g_n$, this means $G$ is finitely generated.

Comment: In the second part, I'm using the fact that if a module is finitely presented (say by generators $A$ with relations $B$), then any finite generating set $A'$ has a finitely generated set of relations.  This is just because it suffices to give the relations $B$ when you express each element of $A$ in terms of $A'$, plus relations that say each element of $A'$ is what you get by first writing each element of $A$ in terms of $A'$ and then writing each element of $A'$ in terms of those elements of $A$.

Comment: (This argument is extremely general and works for any sort of algebraic structure--if one finite presentation exists, then for *any* finite generating set you only need a finite set of relations.)

Comment: Your comment is effectively a proof of Schanuel's lemma, in the case of free modules!  I see that it is intuitive enough that you might want to omit it.

Comment: It is a good thing I never thought of your proof 20 years ago when I started my PhD.  A lot of my early papers were based on a technique that I came up with while justifying Schanuel's lemma to myself a different way!